# How do I get VNC to only serve up a specific display in windows?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, vnc, vncserver

I'm doing this nice little project which will please a bunch of iPod/iPhone users, but one of my last steps requires me to serve up a specific display on my computer, how do I specify which display to use?

I found this quote from a mailing list regarding UltraVNC but I see no option or entry in their server dialogs to enter it...

> Barry,
>
> VNC Server supports remoting of individual monitors' contents via the
>   command-line/registry option DisplayDevice, which should be set to something
>   like:
>
> \.\DISPLAY0 for the primary display
>   \.\DISPLAY1 for the second display
>
> And so on.
>
> Regards,
>
> Wez @ RealVNC Ltd.

Any ideas?  I'd preferably like to avoid using the VNC servers 'area' function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a Stack Overflow question, but I can't be sure because I can't tell for certain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @CarlF: nope, seems more about how to use advanced VNC server options to me.  might be SO if he's trying to programmatically use a VNC-providing library.

Comment: Oohhh ... VNC options.  Got it.

Comment: @ThantiK Have you finished with the software you were busy with? i.e. what did you build exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RealVNC 4.1 documentation](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/winvnc.html#OtherOptions) describes how to use this option.  I haven't seen a specific commandline option to activate it, but you can also add it to the registry.

> **`DisplayDevice=<display>`**
>
> The display device to remote, or empty to remote all displays.
>   The format of display is **`\\.\<device>`**. For example, **`\\.\display1`**.

You need to set or create the `DisplayDevice` key in one of the following places, depending on how you're running the server:

- If running RealVNC server as a service, set/create the key under

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\RealVNC\WinVNC4
  ```
- If running RealVNC server in user-mode, set/create the key under

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\RealVNC\WinVNC4
  ```

I found [some indication](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/vnc/list/58861#58861) that this option might be specified on the commandline like this (no guarantees; I can't test this for you):

```
Winvnc4 -displaydevice=\\.\display1 -portnumber=5900
Winvnc4 -displaydevice=\\.\display2 -portnumber=5901
```

Comment: None of those registry entries exist for UltraVNC, TightVNC.  RealVNC is a commercial package which I don't have the money for in order to get the *same features* as the free VNC servers =/

When trying to run with command line options, it refuses the arguement.

Comment: I added the key and string values for each given VNC program and none of them seem to take when running a new server.

Comment: Got it working with RealVNC; found a free version.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For RealVNC , it seems that one has to have physical secondary monitor attached.
TightVNC doesn't have such requirement.