# I need to send what is on the 6th screen of a Windows 7 machine to another screen

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, vnc

On a computer with 6 screens attached I need to send the content of screen 6 (it can't be the primary monitor) to another screen which isn't physically attached to the computer. The place the image is going to be displayed can be a tv or another computer.

I have tried several vnc options but they don't seem to allow the picking a non-primary screen - they either want to see the primary screen or a combination of all of the screens.

I have tried ultraVNC which only has the ability to show the primary screen or all screens (see this comment from one of the developers: http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?p=64617&sid=1149b11cfbbccd61cd64a71603a0e61e#p64617 )

I have also tried realVNC as per this superuser exchange but the registry options seem to have changed since the version specified here: [How do I get VNC to only serve up a specific display in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/102726/how-do-i-get-vnc-to-only-serve-up-a-specific-display-in-windows)

The distance to this other machine isn't too far but I can't run a cable, and I can't use a IR sender of the image because people walk between the machines regularly.

Any ideas, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real VNC does have the solution...

In this knowledge base article: Can I view only one of the displays of my multiple-monitor computer?

http://kb.realvnc.com/questions/105/Can+I+view+only+one+of+the+displays+of+my+multiple-monitor+computer%3F

It says you can tell it which display to serve using the syntax:

\.\DISPLAY1

So I tried \.\DISPLAY6 which didn't work.

Interestingly under the MAC OS X instructions it says: "By default it is set to "-1", which tells VNC Server to remote all monitors. Setting it to 0 will display the primary monitor, setting it to 1 will display the secondary monitor, and so on."

So I tried \.\DISPLAY5 which worked.