# How to configure RealVNC Viewer to display on only specific monitors instead of all monitors?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, vnc, vnc-viewer

I am trying to configure RealVNC Viewer on Windows 7 64 bit, to use only 2 out of 3 available displays. I could come across UseAllMonitors option, setting which to true uses all 3 monitors, and not just a specific number of displays. Is there any way to do this in Real VNCViewer?

Answer (score 2):

I searched a lot for a solution for this problem but finally I solved the issue on my own.
Download Display Fusion and set up a new function in settings. It should look like this:

[image]

Notice the shortcut. I set it at Shift + Ctrl + W, but you can choose any other setting. Also, the width value is set for two full hd monitors. If you have another resolution, please change this value (both monitors must have the same resolution).

Now make RealVNC full screen, it will span on all three monitors. Press the shortcut and RealVNC will rearange on the two right monitors in fullscreen.

Comment: You need pro to add custom functions

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an option to use 2 out of 3 monitors I'm afraid. The only option is to use all the monitors (set UseAllMonitors to True) or just use one monitor (set UseAllMonitors to False, which is the default). Note, the UseAllMonitors option only take effect when you are in full screen mode.

@vembutech the DisplayDevice option is only in the VNC Server not in the Viewer. The viewer does have an option called Monitor which does allow you to specify which monitor the Viewer's desktop window will appear on using values like \\.\Display1 etc. What you cannot do though is provide a list of displays to use, only one value.

Answer (score 1):

I've sorted the problem with multiple connections to same machine.

Settings:

1. UseAllMonitors: false
2. Fullscreen: true
3. FullScreenChangeResolution: True
4. Scaling: Scale to fit Height

Open first connection, fullscreen it, open second connection (on the entry in address book - [Right Click] -> Duplicate), move it to another monitor, fullscreen it, scroll content to the right (by moving mouse cursor to the edge of the window).

Voila!

This way not only you decide how many monitors you want to use on the local machine for remote viewing, you do not need any third-party software. It is somewhat more heavy on the bandwidth, but nothing is free.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a while to become less stupid and realize what you mean, but the time invested learning this trick, and time spent on every time I need to re-connect, is totally worth it considering the efficiency improvement. My only complaint is I cannot drag windows across monitors since it's fake multi-screen. The development team should really consider making this a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be achieved by changing the "Displaydevice" option in Real VNCViewer. [Refer how to do this](https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/latest/parameters/vncserver.html#displaydevice)

Comment: Well, I've tried that, and moreover, it does not provide any nomenclature on how to specify more than 1 display (\\.\Display1,\\.\Display2 or | separated?). 

Also, I think that page refers to configuration options available to the VNC Server. I am running the VNC Client. A question for that was discussed earlier here: http://superuser.com/questions/102726/how-do-i-get-vnc-to-only-serve-up-a-specific-display-in-windows

Answer (score -1):

If you are connected to a Windows Machine, you can press `CTRL + P` and select `PC screen only`.
This way the host will only use a single monitor and display this one.